# How to read huffman tree frequency from a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, huffman-code

I have to create a huffman tree whose alphabtes(symbols, i mean "aaabbacaccba" etc.) must be given as Input.txt file at sole argument.

I then have to create the frequency corresponding to each  alphabtes.
I have problem in createing frequencies.
I want something like this: suppose if i have to read this in input.txt: `"aabcccadde"`. Then my code must print like this:

```
sym:a, freq:3
sym:b, freq:1
sym:c, freq:3
sym:d, freq:2
sym:e, freq:1
```

My code for this is working correctly: see below:

```
   while (c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '\r') 
   {
    Object1.data[count].symbol = c;
    if(Object1.data[count].symbol =='a')
    {
      save_a++;
    }
    if(Object1.data[count].symbol =='b')
    {
      save_b++;
    }
    if(Object1.data[count].symbol =='c')
    {
      save_c++;
    }
    if(Object1.data[count].symbol =='d')
    {
      save_d++;
    }
    if(Object1.data[count].symbol =='e')
    {
      save_e++;
    }
    count++;
    c = fgetc(input_file);
   }
    cout<< "save_a : "<<save_a <<endl<< "save_b : "<<save_b <<endl<< "save_c: "<<save_c<<endl<< "save_d : "<<save_d <<endl<< "save_e: "<<save_e<<endl;
```

so the output is:

```
save_a : 5
save_b : 3
save_c: 2
save_d : 2
save_e: 3
```

But the problem is when user again changes the frequency to "pqabbaddqpc". The user here added two more alphabets, where i have only counter to read the count of a,b,c,d and e only. I mean i want to create some dynamic kind of system where the user can enter any alphabets to calculate the frequencies.

Is it possible to do achieve this ?
Any help please ?

Comment: You're using the wrong container for this. I would suggest you (a) use a real [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) for reading your file, and (b) use a [`std::unordered_map<char,unsigned int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to establish your frequency counts. Links to both have been provided.

Comment: @WhozCraig Even if i use ifstream. Can i change the characters in Input.txt dynamically and obtain their frequencies , Without declaring extra varibale like save_a to save only a, save_b to only b etc. i mean to store thier occurence count? (as i am doing in my code right now)  ?

Comment: A simple version that takes input from `std::cin` rather than a file [**can be seen here**](http://ideone.com/u5qifA). I think it is what you're trying to do. If you want the output sorted by highest-to-lowest frequency it gets a little more complicated, but not too bad.

Comment: @WhozCraig unordered_map is something i built i guess. But i want to implement myself (without using any inbuilt function). Can you give me any idea for that . Thanks

Comment: If you have no restrictions on what you can use, you'd be crazy not to use the standard library. that's what it is there for. If you have C++ prior to C++11 you can use `std::map<char,unsigned int>` instead. The rest of the code would be the same. Of course you can always build your own hash table implementation and/or BST, etc, but there is no reason to reinvent that wheel if you don't have to (unless of course, you *want* to). But regardless you know how you can do it. Whether it be a standard container or one you build, the idea is the same.

Comment: @WhozCraig i am restricted not to use anything in built. Could you please suggest me ay god link or algorithm or piece of code to help me in what i wanna achieve ? thanks.

Comment: A lookup table solution as Vikram presents below will work as you desire provided you take care to use the proper types and conversion logic. It will also be very fast. Because you're using a limited domain of values (characters) I would recc that approach.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple if you map each alphabet according to its integer value to table which maintains its count .

```
int freq[256];
char c;
while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {

  freq[(unsigned int)c]++;;

}
```

Here as there are only `256 possible characters` so there is no memory overhead as such and then you can easily extract the character present in input as they will have `freq > 0`

Comment: Strictly speaking, those are byte values, not ASCII values - ASCII only defines 0-127...

Comment: @twalberg but still would not matter would it alphabets will be within that range (65,90) and (97,122)

Comment: Correct, this does not affect the algorithm, which is a fairly common way to accomplish calculating the frequency. I was only attempting to correct the notion that there are 255 ASCII values...

Comment: @twalberg there are extended ascii characters that are in range 128-255

Comment: So-called "[Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)" is not [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which is an actual standard published by a standards organization. Some of the things called "Extended ASCII" are also standards, but there is no one standard thing called "Extended ASCII".

Comment: @twalberg okay its in irrelevant to problem so lets rest it here. I have changed my answer to remove that part. I just meant the integer value of a character to be precise not ASCII.

Comment: The premise is sound, only the math is edgy. The assignment will result in an `unsigned char` value for the expression, which has no EOF representation. [See it live](http://ideone.com/2TFxfG). `c` should be `int`, and the index should use `c % 256` for the subscript. Ideally this would use a `(1 << CHAR_BIT)` for both the table dimension and the modulus in conjunction with a `int` type for `c`, but we're reaching the realm of overkill at that point.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that because of the implicit conversion mentioned in my prior comment the posted code will infinitely loop. So you might want to fix that.

Comment: @VikramBhat you forgot to add the declaration of `int c;` (and I suggest against casting down to a type of differing sign-ness).